# How to derive class from Measurement in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, units-of-measurement

I want to derive a class in swift 3 from the Measurement class so I can add additional functionality to define a "Imperial" and "Metric" default unit for each measurement. How do I do this? Following is how I have started.

```
enum UnitOptions { case imperial, metric }

class CustomMeasurement : Measurement {

    let imperialUnit: Unit
    let metricUnit: Unit
    let inputMeasurement = Measurement<Unit>

    init( value: Double, inputUnit: Unit, imperialUnit: Unit, metricUnit: Unit) {
        self.imperialUnit = imperialUnit
        self.metricUnit = metricUnit

        inputMeasurement = Measurement<Unit>( value: value, unit: inputUnit)
    }

    func getMeasurement( unitSystem: UnitOptions) {
        if (unitSystem == .imperial) {
            return inputMeasurement.converted(to: imperialUnit)
        } else {
           return inputMeasurement.converted(to: metricUnit)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to create an extension.  What you've started doing here is actually defining a subClass.  Measurement is actually a ModelType and not a class https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurement (although, I'm not 100% sure if in Swift ModelTypes are just a type of class anyway, so that might not matter).

But to answer the question, there are actually a lot of built in types already that do conversions, so I'm not strictly sure you NEED to do what you are asking.  What is the Imperial version of Centimeters? Is it Inches, or Feet? What's the Imperial version of Millimeters?

Without any extensions, here's what you can do:

```
let testInch : Measurement = Measurement(value: 25, unit: UnitLength.inches)
let testCM : Measurement = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)
var testInMetres = (testInch + testCM).converted(to: UnitLength.meters)
```

Define things as a measurement, with a unit, then you can add, subtract etc. them without any penalty and then just use them as you like later on.

If you want to have an "Imperial" type, I'd do something like this:

```
extension UnitLength {
    static var imperial: UnitLength {
        switch self.baseUnit() {
        case centimeters:
            return UnitLength.inches
        case meters:
            return UnitLength.feet
        default:
            return UnitLength.inches
        }
    }
}
```

We extend the UnitLength type to include a new type "Imperial".  All it does is check the base type, if it's Centimeters, returns the type as Inches, if it's Metres, uses Feet, or defaults to Inches.  You could define a custom treatment of all sorts of UnitTypes for "Imperial" here as you like.

Use it like this:

```
testInMetres.convert(to: UnitLength.imperial) // Returns length in feet.
```

I haven't used Measurement before, this post was really useful as background. https://oleb.net/blog/2016/07/measurements-and-units/

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the thread, but another way, which I think may be preferred, is to extend a subclass (or in your case, many subclasses) of `Dimension`. For instance, here is how you add a new unit, mm/hour, to the `UnitSpeed` class:

```
extension UnitSpeed {
    @nonobjc static let mmPerHour = UnitSpeed(symbol: "mm/hr", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1000.0*3600.0))
}
```

Why is the coefficient `1000.0*3600.0`? Because `UnitSpeed` defines its base unit as meters per second.

You could instead add a variable `@nonobjc static let imperial = milesPerHour`.

More info on [`Dimension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dimension).